# Setting cookie across domains not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm developing a webapp. I'm developing it locally on my machine, running on localhost:8000. The app needs to log in to another server running on my machine at localhost:8888. In production these will be on different subdomains.

My angularjs client code is:

```
postData = new Array('user_id=' + id, 'token=' + token);

$http.post(url, postData.join('&'), {withCredentials:true, headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
    .success(successHandler)
    .error(errorHandler);
```

My server returns a cookie, but that cookie isn't sent on subsequent requests by the browser. My server has the following CORS headers:

```
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept, authorization')
    # self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Max-Age', 21600)
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST')
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000')
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
```

I tried having 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' as '*', but Chrome said I couldn't use a wildcard domain when withCredentials was true.

Chrome still isn't sending the header on subsequent requests to the server.

What am I doing wrong? I'm on OSX and since this will be running with cordova I'm looking for *anything* to get it working for now.